# kubernetes externalname service not reachable by pods in docker-for-desktop windows

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

Hello every one i have created a headless service using ExternalName type to access database residing outside my cluster but i am not able to connect to this service and even ping it from my pods in the cluster .Need help as to what am i doing wrong.I am using the kubernetes that comes shipped with docker-desktop-for-windows

ExternalName service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dbservice
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: geekdude9094  //my hostname
```

results when bin bashing into one of the pods and pinging the service

```
   root@service-app-6ffb5c88fb-5kvcd:/usr/local/tomcat#  ping dbservice
    PING geekdude9094.home (192.168.10.22): 56 data bytes
    92 bytes from broadcom.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from csp3.zte.com.cn.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from broadcom.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from csp3.zte.com.cn.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from broadcom.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from csp3.zte.com.cn.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from broadcom.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    92 bytes from csp3.zte.com.cn.home (192.168.10.1): Destination Host Unreachable
    ^C--- geekdude9094.home ping statistics ---

My windows OS: windows 10 64 bit
kubernetes version: 1.10.11 both client and server
```

Comment: Could you try to ping this one? `dbservice.default.svc.cluster.local`.
If you don't know about your cluster domain name you can use this to find out the dns name:
`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @AlirezaDavoodi tried it but no luck

Comment: Oh Is `geekdude9094` valid DNS? `PING geekdude9094.home`? 
Could you change the `geekdude9094` to `google.com` and recreate the service then check?
What is `geekdude9094`? Is it a service inside the cluster?

Comment: @AlirezaDavoodi geekdude9094 is the name of my machine hosting the db i want to access from the cluster check out my service yml

Comment: @AlirezaDavoodi and yes i can ping google.com from the pod

Comment: Can you run `nslookup dbservice` and send the result?

Comment: @AlirezaDavoodi just reseted my kubernetes cluster will send you after it starts

Comment: nslookup command not found

Comment: Sorry for offtopic but I would like to notice you are using no longer supported version of kubernetes. Read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#supported-versions) more about supported versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you can't access the service is that `docker-desktop-for-windows` run a virtual machine with different networking layers. So from point of networking the cluster cloudn't reach this `192.168.10.1` network because as far as I know, docker windows virtual machine use `10.0.75.0` subnet address.
Maybe you can use this [option](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

Comment: does this means that service with type external name wont work in docker-desktop-for-windows??

Comment: No, it works but the DNS you assigned to `externalName` should be reachable by the `10.0.75.0` network (for example internet) 
Please try this scenario:
modify the service like this `externalName: google.com` and try to ping  `dbservice` again.

Comment: i dont get it must be same for docker -desktop for mac also how come it works on it and not on windows??

Comment: and how does it works on managed or bare metal systems can you please provide links

Comment: Did you try it on mac? I don't think so it works on mac as well.
As I told you before, I think it's a networking issue.

I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST
The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

The gateway is also reachable as gateway.docker.internal.

Comment: ok going to mark your answer as acceepted but one last thing if i want to make it work on baremetal setup will i need to make sure my database is accessible from within the cluster by iptables or something??

Comment: You need to make sure if the cluster from network perspective can access the database network. you can ping the database IP if it works you're good to go.